# Trying to reset Dawnguard in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

After I beat the Dawnguard questline, I decided to try and uninstall the DLC from my console's hard drive to try and reset the storyline. After I uninstalled the DLC from my console and downloaded it again, and then loaded up my save, I was still at the end of the storyline for Dawnguard and nothing had changed. Please help!

Answer (score 8):

The only way to replay the DLC on a Console is to make a new character.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the DLC does not help with the issue, but might lead to a corrupt save if you try to load it without the DLC installed.

Comment: Yes. Quest progress is part of your save and can't be removed.

Comment: On Windows, saving without DLC should allow you to replay the DLC with the same character.

Comment: Well if you can transfer the savegame to a PC, there are certainly tools or console commands to reset all Dawnguard quests, and then you could transfer the savegame back to the console...

Comment: Turning mods on and off is a bad idea. Skyrim stores a lot of mod data in the save games. This can corrupt saves. Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

It'll just work for single quest, so you have to repeat the following:

1. First up, in the game, you need to hit the ` key to bring up the console, or the specific key that you assigned this action to.
2. Then you need to find out what quests you have active, which can easily be done by typing ‘ShowQuestTargets’ and hitting Enter. In case you have many active quests, however, it won’t really be much help, as there are only so many lines the console can show and you can’t scroll its contents. If you know the name of the quest, you can easily look it up on [The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests), which has a full list of the quests in the game, complete with their ID.
3. After finding out what quest you want to progress, you need to enter the ‘Player.sqs’ command, followed by a space and the quest id (final command should look like Player.sqs ). This shows all the stages that are part of this quest, followed by a 1, if you already did it, or a 0, if you didn’t reach it. Bear in mind, however, that there are blank stages, so you might once again want to check out the UESP Wiki to see the actual stages and what they mean.
4. Last but not least, you need to introduce the ‘SetStage’ command, followed by the quest id and the stage number (it should look like SetStage  ). This will automatically progress through the quest to that intended stage, giving you new objectives and, hopefully, fixing the quest.

As a concrete example, say you're stuck on the Dragon Rising quest at the beginning of the game, when the Jarl of Whiterun tells you to investigate a dragon sighting. You need to meet up with Irileth and her guards outside of the town and check out the report.

In case she doesn't spawn at that location and you know that the quest id is MQ104, and that the stage in which Irileth should appear is 15, you just need to enter SetStage MQ104 15. This will automatically get you to the next stage, in which you need to kill the dragon.

Bear in mind that, while this guide may work without a problem, you should always be cautious and do a hard save before attempting to use the Skyrim console.

Comment: Basically correct, but OP stated they're on a console, so they can't access the game's console...

Answer (score 0):

Someone [on the official form](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1460090-restarting-dawnguard/) worked out how to do this:

1. Delete both the Skyrim Update and the Dawnguard DLC.
2. Run Skyrim, get the update again.
3. Run Skyrim, save your game.
4. Download Dawnguard again.

Comment: Please don't post just a link as your answer.